# Pull data from an API endpoint into AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-glue

So I am new to APIs and have this use case where there is order history stored onto a location and the vendor has exposed these as an API endpoint (given a URL along with API keys/parameters etc) I want to pull this data and bring it inside my Redshift table. I want to have the capability to have a job run daily and fetch all new orders for the day into my Redshift table.

Now I was exploring GLUE as it has job creation/scheduling capability but GLUE only supports few data sources using JDBC protocol and couple of non native data sources as well. I could not find anything specific to Glue pulling data from an API endpoint. I wanted to see, if I can utilize other AWS services to do this activity (glue/kinesis??) Any inputs on this would be really helpful. 
Thank in advance.

Comment: You can create a lambda function to capture the response from a API endpoint and store in the redshift table. Also you can configure cloudwatch rule to trigger the lambda function automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to do this but the most Glue way to do it might be to use the new Amazon Athena Query Federation SDK to create a custom API data source. This would allow you to define a table in the AWS Glue Catalog and query this API as if it's just another table. However, this is all in preview and all the dots might not be connected quite yet. So, it might be more hassle than it's worth if your only use case is to sync daily.

[Amazon Athena Query Federation SDK](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-athena-query-federation/releases)